# Using f:ajax to wait for data to finish processing, then update

Tags: java, jsf, jakarta-ee

I'm having a hard time with meshing JSF, AJAX and JavaScript. Here's what I'm trying to do:

When a user submits a form, they're directed to a new page. The page initially checks whether or not their submission has been processed, and if it hasn't, then it displays a progress bar(see [Twitter Bootstrap](http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/components.html#progress)). Then, I use an f:ajax to check if it's finished processed. The *waitForProcessing* method is called; it just waits until processing is set to true and then returns true. At this point, the f:ajax should call the JavaScript to set the progress bar to invisible and then update the page. Here's the code:

```
<ui:define name="content">

        <c:choose>
            <c:when test="#{not submission.isIsProcessed}">
                <f:ajax onevent="setVisibility('processing-dialog', 'none'); setVisibility('processing-backdrop', 'none');" listener="#{submission.waitForProcessing}" status="success" />

                <div class="modal-backdrop fade in" id="processing-backdrop"></div>
                <div id="processing-dialog" class="modal hide fade in" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="false" style="display: block;">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <h3 id="myModalLabel">One sec...</h3>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        <p>We are compiling and running your code!</p>
                        <div class="progress progress-striped active">
                            <div class="bar" style="width: 40%;"></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </c:when>
        </c:choose>
.......
.......
```

A number of things aren't working here. First off, the f:ajax throws an exception because apparently f:ajax can only be nested in certain components. Is there a better way to do this? The goal is to display a progress bar until the backend processing is finished. This processing could potentially take a few minutes, which is why I'm going through the trouble and not having the page just load on its own until the data is ready.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that **f:ajax** does only one execution. If you want to execute the same ajax call multiple times, you should use a **poll** component which is only available in frameworks as PrimeFaces, RichFaces, and others. RichFaces has a component that works exactly as you describe (it uses a poll internally). You can check it here: [RichFaces Progress Bar](http://showcase.richfaces.org/richfaces/component-sample.jsf?demo=progressBar&sample=ajaxProgressBar&skin=blueSky).